# How can I avoid an error from a blank cell in VLookup formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So this is my formula in one of my cells.  The problem is that when I don't have anything in B15, I get the error message.  Sometimes I want it empty, and sometimes I want it to have text in it for this formula.

How do I get this cell to stay blank when there is an error from `B15` not having text but I don't lose the formula when I do put text in `B15`?

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!B15,Sheet3!H9:I10, 2, 0)
```

Comment: not like this...where did I goof?  iferror((=VLOOKUP(Sheet3!B15,Sheet3!H9:I10, 2, 0), ""))

Comment: Nailed it.  Sweetness

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `=VLOOKUP` in an `=IFERROR` and have it return a blank value. Alternatively, you could have it return a message like "No Input Value".

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet3!B15,Sheet3!H9:I10, 2, 0),"")
```